# TypeError: Cannot read property 'spinnerDialog' of undefined Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have created a cordova ionic application. I have an index.html page. I have created templates as well, I navigate between them using state routing. I have one editor.html page. To navigate through this page, I use

> window.open('editor.html')

I have added cordova.js at the top of the scripts in editor.html. I have added spinnerdialog plugin & network information plugin.

When I navigate from any template to editor.html, I use

> window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show("Loading...","Please wait...",
>   true);

to start the loader, but when I come to editor.html,

I'm hiding the loader using :

> window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide();

In editor JS file,I'm getting below error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'spinnerDialog' of undefined**

Can anyone please suggest what I'm missing.

Comment: can you say what is the plugin you are using

Comment: @kirankumar I'm using https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog

Comment: do you have cordova.js linked

Comment: yes I have added, i checked the path too...

Comment: please add `<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.spinnerdialog" />` this line in config.xml and check

Comment: is it necessary to add? Because below code is already added :  `<feature name="SpinnerDialog">
        <param name="android-package" value="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.SpinnerDialog" />
    </feature>`

Comment: can you add that to and check. if their is no change please change the plugin and use this https://github.com/Justin-Credible/cordova-plugin-spinner works perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131477/discussion-between-kiran-kumar-and-anjana-systematix).